# /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

although I've seen similar issues googling, none of the proposed solutions seem to work in my case.

Getting this message when using apt. libapt-pkg.so.5.0 does not seem to be part of release 20.04 and I can't find how to install it.

Any ideas what to do?
Happened after update from 18.04 to 20.04.

Thanks Alex